# Where does de Broglie wavelength $\lambda=h/p$ for massive particles come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

I'm curious where the [de Broglie relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) $p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$ comes from?

I know that for light (which has no rest mass), the following is true:

$E=pc$ and $E=hf$

so,

$$pc=hf \Rightarrow p=\frac{hf}{c}=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$

But how is the expression $p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$ obtained for a massive particle where $E\neq pc$? I've read some people claim that the expression can be derived, and others saying it's an experimentally verified relationship.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is covered nicely in the first (historically oriented) chapter of Weinberg's first book on quantum field theory. Here, he explains the motivation behind De Broglie's hypothesis as follows:

Of course, the main clue was provided by the analogy with radiation. However, there was more: If we want to try to implement wave-particle duality, it must be possible to describe particles my means of a wave with a phase which depends on position and time as:

$$\varphi(\vec x,t)=2\pi (\vec k \cdot \vec x -\nu t)$$

where $\vec k$ is the wave-vector and $\nu$ the frequency of the wave. Now, the key is *Lorentz invariance*. For this phase to stand a chance to be Lorentz invariant, we must have that $\vec k$ and $\nu$ transform under boosts like $\vec x$ and $t$, and hence like $\vec p$ and $E$. This forces them to be proportional, with an identical proportionality constant $\alpha$. From the Einstein relation $E=h\nu$ it is then natural to guess at $\alpha^{-1}=h$, and indeed this gives the correct De Broglie relations, including the ones you quote. Once we accept this, everything follows directly.

As we see, the De Broglie *hypothesis* can be made plausible, but it remains a *hypothesis* that needs to be verified experimentally (and cannot be *proven*).

Comment: I guess that the argument consists in substance to realize that both $\vec{k}$ (from the shape of its contribution to the phase) and $\vec{p}$ (because it is the generator of the Lie spacial translation group) perform a translation of the system by a vector $\vec{x}$; thus they have to be proportional. I am not sure, invoking special relativity is necessary here, or at least I wonder whether it is really necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't $\vec k$ incorporate the $2\pi$ factor in your formula?

Answer (score 0):

The de Brogile supposes that a particle is moving at some speed v, where "E = pv"

In other words, the de Brogile wave is not moving at the speed of light, but at the speed of the particle itself.  This is apparent from $\lambda f$ which gives the speed of the particle.