# $\hbar$ in spin and Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-spin, commutator, physical-constants

The reduced Planck constant $\hbar$ occurs in multiple places in physics. For example, the spin operator of a spin-$\frac12$ particle is given by $$\bf{J}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\bf{\sigma}$$ where $\bf{\sigma}$ is a vector of dimensionless matrices. Also, the Schrödinger equation states that $$i\hbar \frac{\delta}{\delta t}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle$$

In both places, we needed something with unit $Js$ which is the unit of $\hbar$. But it could also have been another number with the unit $Js$. I would like to know if these two appearances of $\hbar $ are related? I think that they can both be derived by measurements. But is it also possible to start reasoning from one (like the $\hbar$ Schrödinger Equation) and prove the other (like the $\hbar$ in the spin operator? Or can both be derived from a single, more general formula?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315776/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375755/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Indeed, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/367028/66086) Goes to the heart of your question. The spin 1/2 proportionality above is pegged to the quantization of orbital angular momentum, following from the Born-Heisenberg commutator, and SU(2) representation theory.