# de Broglie wavelength for particles with mass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, momentum, mass, wavelength

is $p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$ only true for massless particles? because generally $E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$, then if we equate it to $h\nu$ we get $$p=\sqrt{\frac{h^2}{\lambda^2}-m^2c^2}\neq\frac{h}{\lambda}$$

Comment: See this previous question and answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139641/

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\lambda\nu=c$, which is *not true* for massive particle d-B waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relativistic energy-momentum relation:
$$p_\mu p^\mu = (p^0)^2 - \vec p^2= m_0^2 c^2$$
where
$$p^0 c=E=\hbar \omega \qquad p^i = \hbar k^i$$
subject to $|k|=2\pi/\lambda$ and $\omega = 2\pi\nu$.

Therefore, generally
$$|p| = \sqrt{\frac{h^2 \nu^2}{c^2}-m_0^2 c^2}=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$

**Only** for a massless particle ($m_0=0$) the energy-momentum relation reduces to
$$|p|=\frac{h \nu}{c}=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$
or
$$\nu =\frac{c}{\lambda}$$
But this does not limit the validity of the more general energy-momentum relation above.